# Scikit learn Custom Transformer dimension mismatch

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I'm coming from R, so scikit API still very confusing to me. I was following this tutorial http://michelleful.github.io/code-blog/2015/06/20/pipelines/ to learn about Pipelines. So let's create a fake dataset just for reference:

```
x1,x2,y
foo,zoo,1
bar,moo,2
goo,too,3
roo,zoo,4
too,moo,5
```

My goal is very simple: train a linear regression on y, using separate tfidf matrices from x1 and x2, plus some custom features from both x1 and x2 (ie, word length, etc).

Let's start with the simpler task of using only tfidf from x1. Here's the full code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_log_error
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, make_scorer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import re
import math

def clip_RMSLE(y, y_pred, **kwargs):
    y_pred[y_pred < 0] = 0.0
    to_sum = [(math.log(y_pred[i] + 1) - math.log(y[i] + 1)) ** 2.0 for i,pred in enumerate(y_pred)]
    return (sum(to_sum) * (1.0/len(y))) ** 0.5

class ColumnNgram(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, colname, tokenizer, ngram_rg):
        self.colname = colname
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.ngram_rg = ngram_rg
        self.tfidf = None

    def transform(self, df, y=None):
         tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=self.tokenizer, ngram_range=self.ngram_rg)
         return tfidf.fit_transform(df[self.colname].values)

    def fit(self, df, y=None):
        return self


start = time.time()
seed = 1991
ngram_rg = (1,2)
RMSLE = make_scorer(clip_RMSLE, greater_is_better=False)

def tokenizer(text):
    if text:
        result = re.findall('[a-z]{2,}', text.lower())
    else:
        result = []
    return result

df = pd.read_csv('fake.csv', sep=',')
y = df['y'].values

pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', ColumnNgram('x1', tokenizer, ngram_rg)),
('linear_reg', LinearRegression(n_jobs=1))
])

kfold = KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, df, y, cv=kfold, scoring=RMSLE)
print(results)
print(results.mean())

end = time.time()
print('Timeto finish this thing: %0.2fs' % (end - start))
```

I'm getting the error `ValueError: dimension mismatch`, probably because some terms will not appear in both train/validation folds. What's the proper way of doing this? Thank you!

Comment: please add the full code

Comment: Ok, I'll add the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your ColumnNgram to this:

```
class ColumnNgram(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, colname, tokenizer, ngram_rg):
        self.colname = colname
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.ngram_rg = ngram_rg
        self.tfidf = None

    def transform(self, df, y=None):
        return self.tfidf.transform(df[self.colname].values)

    def fit(self, df, y=None):
        self.tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=self.tokenizer, ngram_range=self.ngram_rg)
        self.tfidf.fit(df[self.colname].values)
        return self
```

You should declare and learn about the training data in `fit()`. Currently you are re-fitting the data in each call to `transform()`, which obviously will return in different features in train and validation sets as you have suggested.

The proper way is to keep a `TfidfVectorizer` which learns data during the fit() and then only transform the new data in `transform()` instead of re-fitting the new data.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `return` for your transform method?

Comment: @Jarad. Yes, I should have. That was a type. Fixed now. Thanks